# javascript image object

Tags: javascript, image, object

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetSrc(elem)
    {
        alert ( elem.src );
    }

</script>

<img src="images/yourimage.extn" id="img1" onclick="GetSrc(this);" />
```

i want to convert elem.src to string, String(elem.src); not working

Comment: elem.src is already a string, you can assign it to another string object or if you still have doubts, you can use .toString() method

Answer (score 3):

It's already a string. You could also try:

```
var srcString = new String(elem.src);
```

but it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can already use the source as a string.

```
alert( document.getElementById("img1").src ); // images/yourimage.extn
```

You can set it too:

```
function GetSrc(elem) {
  elem.src = "http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/images/c/ca/String.gif";
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a string itself. No need to again convert to string.

```
alert ( typeof(elem.src) );
```

will give you a string